# Symfony Get a file path into a twig template, the file is in customBundle:Resources:views not in web dir

Tags: symfony, twig, filepath

In one of my twig template, I have a javascript block
where i must give the path of a certain html file. 
I have tried this but having console error

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$("#content").builder({
themeFile: '{{ "ContentbuildBundle:Template:theme.html.twig" }}',
toolbar: 'right',
onRender: function() {
$('#contentarea').trigger('focusout');
}
});
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDOh5.png)

Comment: if I move the file to public directory and make the symlink to web
then easily I can get the path like this
themeFile: '{{ asset("bundle/contenbuild/template/theme.html.twig" }}',
But I dont want to keep the file public :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using twig, you can link to your assets using the `asset` twig function as described on [Twig Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating.html#linking-to-assets)

Unfortunately, I think this function only link to public files, that is, files located on `web` dir.

Also, you can render the content of your HTML using the [include](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html) function.

Can you specify what do you need to achieve? **Remember that it is not possible to access files outside your public dir.**

**EDIT:**
In case you need render some HTML, you should place it on the `resouces`dir (private) and iclude it using twig.

Comment: Thanks man, 
I have a list of articles as html (and i just render them to the front). 
And ya I think of moving it to the public dir and mike it easy

Comment: @Issac How do I access the files I've put in app/Resources/public from twig? I don't want to make these files public.

Comment: @utkarsh2k2 I would suggest you to create a new controller action that returns the private files. You can this way call this action through AJAX from your frontend and get your private file.